# Building Data warehouse/OLAP database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

Building Datawarehouse / OLAP database on SQL Server.

Please let me know steps involved.

Note: I'm not trying to create cube, I know how to do it from Visual Studio but I'm trying to create OLAP database in Analysis Services server.

Is that the idea way to start. Let me know.

I don't see "add new a data source" on SSMS - Server type: Analysis Services Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the database in Visual Studio (aka BIDS), and then deploy it to Analysis Services server.   You cannot create an SSAS database in SSMS.

Comment: I'm trying to build a data warehouse so that other analysts can connect and work. So even for that i have build the database in BIDS??? If there are some best practice, pls let me know.

Comment: Yes, exactly.   Best practice would be to also store the BIDS project in SourceSafe or a similar repository for source control if multiple analysts will be working on it.   Actually, technically, you can avoid BIDS by hand-writing an XMLA script to create the database and executing it in SSMS.  But I wouldn't do it that way.